# Responsive table rendering, with headers that accommodate to new layout

Tags: javascript, css-tables

Is there some way of making table responsive, in such a way that this-:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│         │ ENTITY 1│  ENTITY 2│
├─────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ HEADER 1│    data │     data │
│ HEADER 2│    data │     data │
│ HEADER 3│    data │     data │
│ HEADER 4│    data │     data │
│ HEADER 5│    data │     data │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

becomes this (below say 800px browser width)-:

```
    ┬─────────┬──────────┐
    │ ENTITY 1│  ENTITY 2│
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │       HEADER 1     │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │    data │     data │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │       HEADER 2     │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │    data │     data │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │       HEADER 3     │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │    data │     data │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │       HEADER 4     │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │    data │     data │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │       HEADER 5     │
    ┼─────────┼──────────┤
    │    data │     data │
    ┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

Can this be done with CSS only, or one would need to use JavaScript?

Comment: try the jquery footable plugin.

Comment: It seems that Bootstrap should handle it.

Comment: You *could* do this with a ton of css media queries and divs styled as table elements, but it would be much easier with javascript.

Comment: @Sushil you mean like this - http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/group-headers.htm, that however doesn't give desired layout from pic above.

Comment: yes @branquito. but footable does it in a different way. if you're fine with it then you can use it.

Comment: I tried making a CSS solution, but it's quite fragile (adherent to specific HTML structure) - generally, I think you'd be better served looking at a plugin or existing framework. http://jsfiddle.net/9szvaqch/ (Note that I also gave up using a table, so the HTML is 100% not semantic.)

Comment: Well I would, but couldn't find a framework that deals with it, in such a way..

Comment: If I had to make such a table, I’d put it in a div with overflow-x: scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cell {
  text-align: center;
}
.cell:nth-child(1) { display: none; }

.mobile-row {
  display: table;
  width: 200%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-row > td {
  width: 100%;
}


.no-mobile {
  display: none;
  @media (min-width: 704px) {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="no-mobile"></th>
    <th>ENTITY 1</th>
    <th>ENTITY 2</th>  
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="mobile-row">
      <td>Header 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Header 1</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mobile-row">
      <td>Header 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Header 1</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mobile-row">
      <td>Header 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">Header 1</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff</td>
      <td class="cell">Stuff 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could maybe think about having an extra hidden row for mobile view.
See my mobile first style.